# unit testing complex factory in angularjs that have so many dependency

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Here is the signature

```
.factory('authService', ['$resource', '$rootScope', 'localStorageService', 'permissionModel', 'session', 'AUTH_EVENTS', 'events', '$q', 'configurationModel',
        function ($resource, $rootScope, localStorageService, permissionModel, session, AUTH_EVENTS, events, $q, configurationModel) {
    // code ;
}
```

This factory has a dependency and that dependency is part of another module. I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: Load the two modules in beforeEach: `beforeEach(module('module1', 'module2'));` Where's the problem?

Comment: Actually problem is that in the module it self have so many dependency so someone suggested me to test services so it will help you  but in services dependency complexity is there